# Why is the value of my textarea input being truncated?

Tags: forms

When I receive the form data via email the values of the comments text areas are being truncated.

This is the code.

```
if($_GET['section'] == '2'){

  $pups_num = $_SESSION['pups_seen'];
  $pups_num_not = $_SESSION['pups_not_seen'];
  return drupal_render(drupal_get_form('my_form_2',$pups_num, $pups_num_not));

}elseif($_GET['section'] == '3'){

  echo '<p>Thank you! Your monthly puppy counselor report has been submitted with the information shown below. If you have any questions about the report, please contact Puppy Development at ***-***-****</p>';
  echo '<h2>New Puppy Counselor Monthly Report submission</h2>';
  echo '<p>Puppy Counselor name/group: '.$_SESSION['name'].'<br>
        Email: '.$_SESSION['email'].'<br>
        Month of report: '.$_SESSION['month'].'<br>
        Group outings planned: '.$_SESSION['outings'].'</p>';
  echo '<h2>Puppies Seen - '.$_SESSION['pups_seen'].'</h2>';
  $puppy_stat_array = $_SESSION['seen_pup_stats'];

  foreach ($puppy_stat_array as $pup) {
      $each_pup = explode(",",$pup);
      echo '<p>Puppy #: '.$each_pup[0].
           '<br>Puppy name: '.$each_pup[1].
           '<br>Raiser name: '.$each_pup[2].
           '<br>Comments: '.$each_pup[3].'</p>';
  }

  echo '<h2>Puppies Not Seen - '.$_SESSION['pups_not_seen'].'</h2>';
  $not_puppy_stat_array = $_SESSION['not_seen_pup_stats'];

  foreach ($not_puppy_stat_array as $pup) {
      $each_pup = explode(",",$pup);
      echo '<p>Puppy #: '.$each_pup[0].
           '<br>Puppy name: '.$each_pup[1].
           '<br>Raiser name: '.$each_pup[2].
           '<br>Comments: '.$each_pup[3].'</p>';
  }


}else{

  echo '<p>There are three sections to this form. Please fill out the form as follows:</p>
  <ul>
  <li>Report Information – All information is required in this section</li>
  <li>Puppies Seen – Enter amount of puppies seen this month</li>
  <li>Puppies Not Seen This Month – Enter amount of puppies NOT seen this month</li></ul>
  <p>( You will enter puppy information on the next page )</p>';

  return drupal_render(drupal_get_form('my_form'));
}

/* =================================== FORM 2 ====================================*/
function my_form_2($form, &$form_state, $p, $np) {

$form['contact_label'] = array(
  '#type' => 'item',
  '#markup' => '<h2 class="horizontalR_below" style="width:50%">Puppies Seen</h2>',
);

for ($i = 0; $i < $p; $i++) {
$form['puppies']['#tree'] = TRUE;
  // puppy number field
$form['puppies'][$i]['pup_num'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Puppy Number:',
    '#size' => '20',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="component-input-textfield">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

// puppy name field
$form['puppies'][$i]['pup_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Puppy Name:',
    '#size' => '20',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="component-input-textfield">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

// puppy name field
$form['puppies'][$i]['raiser_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Raiser Name:',
    '#size' => '20',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="component-input-textfield">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

// puppy name field
$form['puppies'][$i]['comments'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#cols' => 20, 
    '#rows' => 5,
    '#title' => 'Comments:',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="component-input-textarea">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

}

$form['not_seen_label'] = array(
  '#type' => 'item',
  '#markup' => '<h2 class="horizontalR_below" style="width:50%">Puppies NOT Seen</h2>',
);

for ($i = 0; $i < $np; $i++) {
$form['no_puppies']['#tree'] = TRUE;

  // puppy number field
$form['no_puppies'][$i]['pup_number'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Puppy Number:',
    '#size' => '20',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="component-input-textfield">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

// puppy name field
$form['no_puppies'][$i]['pup_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Puppy Name:',
    '#size' => '20',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="component-input-textfield">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

// puppy name field
$form['no_puppies'][$i]['raiser_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Raiser Name:',
    '#size' => '20',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="component-input-textfield">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

// puppy name field
$form['no_puppies'][$i]['comments'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#cols' => 20, 
    '#rows' => 5,
    '#title' => 'Comments:',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="component-input-textarea">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#attributes' => array(
    'class' => array('no_pup_comment_textarea'))
  );

}

// submit button
 $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
    '#attributes' => array(
    'class' => array('form_submit_btn'))
  );
return $form;
}
/* =================================== FORM 1 ====================================*/
function my_form() {

// creates a address label
$form['contact_label'] = array(
  '#type' => 'item',
  '#markup' => '<br><h3 class="horizontalR_below">Report Information</h3>',
);
// fist name field
$form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Puppy counselor name/group:',
    '#size' => '20',
    '#required' => TRUE
  );

// email
  $form['email'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Email'),
    '#size' => '20',
    '#attributes' =>array('placeholder' => t('E-mail address')),
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

// month
  $form['month'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Month of report:'),
    '#size' => '20',
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

// generic text area
$form['outings'] = array(
'#title' => t('What outings were planned for your group?'),
'#type' => 'textarea',
'#cols' => 60, 
'#rows' => 5,
'#required' => TRUE
);

// creates a puppy seen label
$form['ps'] = array(
  '#type' => 'item',
  '#markup' => '<br><h3 class="horizontalR_below">Puppies Seen</h3>',
);

// number of pups seen field
$form['num_of_pups_seen'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Number of Puppies seen',
    '#size' => '5',
    '#required' => TRUE
  );

// creates a puppy seen label
$form['pns'] = array(
  '#type' => 'item',
  '#markup' => '<br><h3 class="horizontalR_below">Puppies NOT Seen</h3>',
);

// number of pups not seen field
$form['num_of_pups_not_seen'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Number of Puppies NOT seen',
    '#size' => '5',
    '#required' => TRUE
);

// submit button
 $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Next'),
    '#attributes' => array(
    'class' => array('form_submit_btn'))
  );
  return $form;
}


// email validation function
function my_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $valid_email = $form_state['values']['email'];
  $valid_pups_seen = $form_state['values']['num_of_pups_seen'];
  $valid_pups_not_seen = $form_state['values']['num_of_pups_not_seen'];
  if (!valid_email_address($valid_email)) {
  form_set_error('email', 'Sorry. Your email address,' . $valid_email . ', is not valid. Please submit a valid E-mail address.');
  }
  if(!is_numeric($valid_pups_seen)){
    form_set_error('num_of_pups_seen', 'Sorry '. $valid_pups_seen . ', is not a number. Please submit a valid number.');
  }
  if(!is_numeric($valid_pups_not_seen)){
    form_set_error('num_of_pups_not_seen', 'Sorry '. $valid_pups_not_seen . ', is not a number. Please submit a valid number.');
  }

} // end email validate function

// mailer function
function my_form_2_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  $headers = array(
    'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
    'Content-Type' => 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8;',
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => '8Bit',
    'X-Mailer' => 'Drupal'
  );
  foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
    $message['headers'][$key] = $value;
  }
  $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
  $message['body'] = $params['body'];
} 
// end mailer function

function my_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {


   $_SESSION['email'] = $form_state['values']['email'];
   $_SESSION['name'] = $form_state['values']['name'];
   $_SESSION['month'] = $form_state['values']['month'];
   $_SESSION['outings'] = $form_state['values']['outings'];
   $_SESSION['pups_seen'] = $form_state['values']['num_of_pups_seen'];
   $_SESSION['pups_not_seen'] = $form_state['values']['num_of_pups_not_seen'];

   drupal_goto('puppy-councel-test-form', array('query'=>array('section'=>'2')));

}
function my_form_2_submit($form, &$form_state) {

    $seen_pups_array = array();
    $counter = $_SESSION['pups_seen'];
    for ($i=0; $i < $counter ; $i++) { 
      $pup_stats = $form_state['values']['puppies'][$i]['pup_num'].','.$form_state['values']['puppies'][$i]['pup_name'].','.$form_state['values']['puppies'][$i]['raiser_name'].','.$form_state['values']['puppies'][$i]['comments'];
      array_push($seen_pups_array, $pup_stats);
    }
    $_SESSION['seen_pup_stats'] = $seen_pups_array;

    $not_seen_pups_array = array();
    $ncounter = $_SESSION['pups_not_seen'];
    for ($i=0; $i < $ncounter ; $i++) { 
      $npup_stats = $form_state['values']['no_puppies'][$i]['pup_number'].','.$form_state['values']['no_puppies'][$i]['pup_name'].','.$form_state['values']['no_puppies'][$i]['raiser_name'].','.$form_state['values']['no_puppies'][$i]['comments'];
      array_push($not_seen_pups_array, $npup_stats);
    }
    $_SESSION['not_seen_pup_stats'] = $not_seen_pups_array;

    $from = 'info@test.org';
    $body[] = 'Counselor Info<hr>'.
              '<br><p> Name/Group: '.$_SESSION['name'].
              '<br> Email: '.$_SESSION['email'].
              '<br> Month: '.$_SESSION['month'].
              '<br> Outings: '.$_SESSION['outings'].'</p>';

              $body[] .='Puppies Seen - '.$_SESSION['pups_seen'].'<hr><br>';

              $puppy_stat_array = $_SESSION['seen_pup_stats'];
                foreach ($puppy_stat_array as $pup) {
                    $each_pup = explode(",",$pup);
                    $body[] .= '<p>Puppy #: '.$each_pup[0].
                         '<br>Puppy name: '.$each_pup[1].
                         '<br>Raiser name: '.$each_pup[2].
                         '<br>Comments: '.$each_pup[3].'</p>';
                }


    $body[] .=  'Puppies NOT Seen - '.$_SESSION['pups_not_seen'].'<hr><br>';
                $not_puppy_stat_array = $_SESSION['not_seen_pup_stats'];
                foreach ($not_puppy_stat_array as $pup) {
                    $each_pup = explode(",",$pup);
                    $body[] .= '<p>Puppy #: '.$each_pup[0].
                         '<br>Puppy name: '.$each_pup[1].
                         '<br>Raiser name: '.$each_pup[2].
                         '<br>Comments: '.$each_pup[3].'</p>';
                }


    $to = 'test@email.com'; // Set this email address - emails will be sent to this email address!  
    $params = array(
    'body' => $body,
    'subject' => 'Monthly Puppy Counselor Report',
    );
    if (drupal_mail('my_form_2', 'some_mail_key', $to, language_default(), $params, $from, TRUE))
    {
        drupal_set_message('Thank you for your report.');
    } else {
        drupal_set_message('Sorry, there was an error sending your report. Please try again later');
    }

    drupal_goto('puppy-councel-test-form', array('query'=>array('section'=>'3')));
}
```

If I put this into the comment text area, I get "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, maxime, at, praesentium est molestiae totam laborum natus reprehenderit suscipit officiis itaque nulla exercitationem asperiores! Architecto, nam ducimus explicabo officiis dolore cupiditate cum quas facilis dolor suscipit quaerat ipsa? Impedit sed recusandae voluptatem. Quo, veritatis, harum quis officia aliquam explicabo amet.

Comment: Could you truncate your form and remove all unneeded form elements? Do you really need all these puppy data to show the comment issue? And why do you echo so much data, instead of using Drupal's built-in flow?

Comment: I'm very new to drupal and I'm not familiar with "built-in flow" They are dynamically create form elements base on what is selected in the first step of the form. I don't know if that answers your question. I need to know why the value of the text areas is being truncate by the time it reaches the email destination.

Comment: And glancing for a moment at your code I haven't even **seen** the definition of a forms element that gave you problems, so unless you truncate your code to minimal part that demonstrates your issue, I will not bother to try to answer. Maybe someone else will, but it's not really inviting. See http://sscce.org